# AngularJS: routeChangeError different from $routeProvider.otherwise?

Tags: angularjs, redirect, error-handling, routes

Currently I have $routeProvider.otherwise configured to go to a page behind the login, and if that page does not resolve, they go to the login screen. I would like an additional redirection to an error page when an XHR fails that is meant to redirect the user to a success page. I have found that if I register a listener on routeChangeError to redirect to /error instead of the defaults, the .otherwise is overridden and all mistyped links take the user to the error page. Does angular provide anything that allows for this? Or maybe I missed something in my code? I can write it if angular doesn't provide it, but I'm just wondering if there is a feature native to the framework.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function () {
    $location.path("/login")
})
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $route) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/error', {
            templateUrl: 'error.html',
            controller: 'Error',
            controllerAs: 'error'
        }).
        when('/status-info', {
            templateUrl: 'status-page.html',
            controller: 'StatusInfoController',
            resolve: {
                auth: function (SessionService) {
                    return SessionService.resolve()
                }
            }
        }).
        when('/', {
            redirectTo: '/status-info'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
```

### Additional info

The desired outcome is a website that responds to incorrect URLs in the usual way - defaulting to a specific page behind login or login if not authenticated, but with the extra twist of having a special error page for rejected `$route.resolve()` promises.

I would love to write a plunkr for you, but I can't get to it tonight. We're launching the beta this weekend! I don't necessarily need code if you can just set me in the right direction. Any help you can offer would be great.

Comment: If there's no matching route, ngRoute falls back to 'otherwise'. If there is matching route but there are rejected promises in route dependencies (including templateUrl request), $routeChangeError is fired. Please, clarify what you expect and what you get, a plunker would help.

Comment: I'm feeling pretty dumb. I can just put the conditional check in the routechange listener

Comment: I'm sleep deprived